# IE quirks mode a:hover style issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, anchor

I have a span that I only want to show when the cursor hovers over it. To see what I expect please remove the "href" attribute and try it in a non-IE browser.

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            color: orange;
        }
        a.anchor {
            text-decoration:none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: default;
        }
        a.anchor:hover span {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        a.anchor span {
            visibility: hidden;
        }       
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="anchor" href="#">
            <span>XXXXXXXXX</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that the doctype is commented out to put IE into quirks mode. In this mode, IE a:hover does not work with the listed CSS (visibility changer) UNLESS the anchor contains a "href" attribute.

However, by adding "href" IE overwrites the span's style with the browsers default anchor styles. In my app, the container div could have dynamic styles making it hard to over-over-write the anchor's style...

So my questions are:

1) I can only work with quirks mode. Is there anyway for me to get the :hover behavior the way I wanted without using the href attribute?

2) If the answer to the previous question is no, what is the best way to remove all the browser default anchor styles?

I am really hoping to not write script for this, but if there is any script solution please do let know!

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: `button.onMouseOver = function(){ document.getElementById("thespan").style.display = 'inline'; };  button.onMouseOut = function(){ document.getElementById("thespan").style.display = 'none'; };`

Comment: What is an anchor without a href attribute? Usually you'd only do that to mark places in a page (with an ID), which normally aren't displayed.

Comment: Try adding the name attribute to your `a` tag. In HTML4 the tag must have either a href or name attribute, so I can only guess that your `a` is actually just being displayed as an ordinary `div` until you add the required attributes.

Try adding `!important` to your styles and see if this is enough to overwrite the default.

Comment: @animuson: From what I see, an anchor as described by the HTML spec is an `a` element *without* a `href` attribute. One that has that attribute is a link. (It's annoying because `a` does stand for "anchor", but is mostly used for creating hyperlinks...)

Comment: the reason for using an <a> here is that in IE7- :hover is not supported on other element types.

Comment: also, adding name alone doesn't do it for IE7

Comment: also, invisible/hidden element will not receive mouse events

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    a.anchor:hover span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    a.anchor span {
        display: none;
    }
```

included example http://jsfiddle.net/gHKsY/4/

Comment: This is not exactly what i needed. The anchor needs to be completely invisible when the cursor is not over it.

Comment: Thats fine, just set the background as transparent on the anchor :}

Comment: Only used the colors so you could test.

Comment: my goal was really to be able to get rid of the "href" because it is messing up my styles...

Comment: You would definitely have to use a JavaScript solution then, sorry. Check out Tims comment above.